# Example of Banach-valued map that is bounded but not riemann-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional real Banach space. It is well-known that in this context, the Darboux-integrable maps for a (in general) proper subspace of the Riemann-integrable maps of the form $f:[a,b]\to X$.

Moreover, the Riemann-integrable maps continue to form a subspace of the bounded maps of the form $f:[a,b]\to X$. In a finite-dimensional setting, say $\mathbb{R}$, the Dirichlet Function is an example of a bounded map that fails to be Riemann-integrable.

**My question is the following:** Does there exist a map of the form $f:[a,b]\to X$ which is bounded but not Riemann-integrable?

Comment: Howabout generalising the idea of the Dirichlet function? Let $x$ in $X$ and set $f = x \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b]}$, for some $x \in X$.

Comment: Yes, this may work for some $X$'s, but I think it will depend on the space. For example, if $r_{1},r_{2},r_{3},\ldots$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, then the map from $[0,1]$ into $c_{0}$ defined by $f(r_{n})=e_{n}$ (the sequence of all zeros except for a $1$ in the nth slot) and $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$ in $[0,1]$ is actually Riemann-integrable!

Comment: I believe @Jonas meant a fixed $x$, e.g. following your notation $f(r_n)=e_1$.

Comment: @Dunham, yes that seems right. Thank you!